# Não consigo iniciar nodemon

Tags: javascript, node.js, aplicação-web, api

estou tentando inicializar com nodemon um projeto com acesso ao postgre porem ele não inicia ao rodar o comando.
segue o erro :

```
Error: listen EADDRINUSE :::3000
    at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:1018:11)
    at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:1041:20)
    at Server._listen2 (net.js:1258:14)
    at listen (net.js:1294:10)
    at Server.listen (net.js:1390:5)                                                                         17:24)
    at EventEmitter.listen (C:\Users\ERNETWORK\Desktop\Ultimaversao\node_modules\express\lib\application.js:6
17:24)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\ERNETWORK\Desktop\Ultimaversao\js\model.js:347:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
```

Comment: pode mostrar o código fonte?

Comment: Matheus, esse erro diz que o servidor que estás a iniciar quer usar uma porta que já está a ser usada. Tens a certeza que não tens 2 programas iguais a correr.

Comment: vou verificar. Obrigado

Comment: alterei a porta, mas agora  aparece outra mensagem de erro .

Comment: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\ERNETWORK\Desktop\Ultimaversao\model.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:390:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:505:3

Comment: Esse erro vem de algum dos ficheiros do projeto? ou das dependencias somente?

Comment: possivelmente das dependencias

Comment: Como foi instalado o nodemon? você instalou ele globalmente?